# How to map an Oracle NUMBER to a C# type with Entity Framework without exceptions

Tags: c#, oracle, linq, entity-framework-6

We have a table in Oracle 12 (11 in production), with a column with type `NUMBER` with unspecified precision and scale. I try to load it into an `decimal`, but I get an `InvalidCastException`. Sure, not every NUMBER can fit into a decimal, but the used values are not that high:

```
1000
0.2777777777778
9.76944444444444  (only this value causes an exception)
277.7777777778
1
```

When I copy/paste these values into C#, there is no problem:

```
decimal thisWorks = 9.76944444444444m;
```

It doesn't help when I specify precision `HasPrecision(38,19)` with the Fluent API. I also narrowed the Linq query down to only the row and column I need.

Then I decided to use a `string` type, so I can do the conversion myself later. But that results in the exact same exception with the exact same strack-trace... Stack-trace (application specific part removed):

```
Result Message: 
Test method NimbusT.UnitTests.Data.Repositories.EntityRepositories.TUnitRepositoryTest.SelectAll_Test threw exception: 
System.InvalidCastException: Specified cast is not valid.
Result StackTrace:  
at Oracle.ManagedDataAccess.Client.OracleDataReader.GetDecimal(Int32 i)
   at Oracle.ManagedDataAccess.Client.OracleDataReader.GetValue(Int32 i)
   at System.Data.Entity.Core.Common.Internal.Materialization.Shaper.ErrorHandlingValueReader`1.GetUntypedValueDefault(DbDataReader reader, Int32 ordinal)
   at System.Data.Entity.Core.Common.Internal.Materialization.Shaper.ErrorHandlingValueReader`1.GetValue(DbDataReader reader, Int32 ordinal)
   at System.Data.Entity.Core.Common.Internal.Materialization.Shaper.GetColumnValueWithErrorHandling[TColumn](Int32 ordinal)
   at lambda_method(Closure , Shaper )
   at System.Data.Entity.Core.Common.Internal.Materialization.Coordinator`1.ReadNextElement(Shaper shaper)
   at System.Data.Entity.Core.Common.Internal.Materialization.Shaper`1.SimpleEnumerator.MoveNext()
   at System.Data.Entity.Internal.LazyEnumerator`1.MoveNext()
   at System.Collections.Generic.List`1..ctor(IEnumerable`1 collection)
   at System.Linq.Enumerable.ToList[TSource](IEnumerable`1 source)
```

Seems the `Oracle.ManagedDataAccess.Client` (the one we use) uses GetDecimal for the string type as well.

When I use `double` as column type there is no problem, but we don't want to use doubles. This problem is probably the easiest to solve by applying a specific precision to the column, but database changes are pretty difficult around here.

Does anyone have an idea how to work with this, without database changes?

Comment: [This seems to be expected according to the docs](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/yk72thhd.aspx)...

Comment: Not really in the described case. 1) my number has 16 positions, which should perfectly fit into a decimal; 2) it generates a overflow when I want it as a string value... 3) I use Entity Framework, not ADO.NET

Comment: Can you create  a view of a sample table and cast the Number to double? In EF you can create a primary key on a view that is disabled to fool it into seeing it as a table as long as you have the primary key in the view

Comment: ODP.NET - a typical Oracle buggy crap. See here http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/topics/dotnet/downloads/odpnet-ef-nuget-121022-2585735.txt, N:7. They speak for a `known issues", "workarounds", "casts" (whatever that means) instead of just fixing the obvious bugs in the software.

Comment: I also tried OracleDecimal, but mapping doesn't seem to be supported...